# Proving a relation involving the median and sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have tried to prove the relation below, but it seems not too clear.

> Given the diagram below, Prove that:
>   $$\frac{d^{2}}{2} + 2a^{2} = a_{1}^{2} + a_{2}^{2}$$
>    [image: Diagram]

Comment: FYI: This is a special case (with a median) of [Stewart's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem).

Comment: @Adrián Naranjo See Apollonius theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27_theorem).

Comment: @Jean Marie I'm damiliar with Apollonius theroem, and that you use the cosine rule to prove it. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your thanks :) My remark is general about "labelled results" as is the case here. 1°) I do think that it is necessary to indicate already known results by their name if they have one 2°) Known results do not need necessarily to be demonstrated anew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we will work on the right triangle. Using the cosine rule we get $$a_2^2=a^2+\frac{d^2}{4}-ad\cos(\theta) \: \: \: (1)$$ Using the cosine rule in the left triangle, and the trigonometric identity $\cos(\pi-\theta)=-\cos(\theta)$ we get: $$a_1^2=a^2+\frac{d^2}{4}-ad\cos(\pi-\theta)=a^2+\frac{d^2}{4}+ad\cos(\theta) \: \: \: (2).$$ If we add equations (1) and (2) we get $$a_1^2+a_2^2=2a^2+2\cdot \frac{d^2}{4}-ad\cos(\theta)+ad\cos(\theta)=2a^2+\frac{d^2}{2}$$ and we're done!

**EDIT:** To prove the identity $\cos(\pi-\theta)=-\cos(\theta)$ we use the well-known identity $$\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta),$$ and the fact that $\sin(\pi)=0$ and $\cos(\pi)=-1$. Setting $\alpha:=\theta$ and $\beta=\pi$ in the above identity yields $$\cos(\pi-\theta)=\cos(\theta-\pi)=\cos(\theta)\cos(\pi)+\sin(\alpha)\sin(\pi)=\cos(\theta)(-1)+0=-\cos(\theta).$$

Comment: Thanks. I am seeing this trigonometric identity for the first time. Can you include a short proof for this nice relation?

Comment: Done! If you need anything else let me know :)

Comment: Thanks! From the nice Proof above, it seems $\alpha$ should be set to $\pi$

Comment: It really doesn't matter, cos is an even function; that is, cos(x)=cos(-x) for any real number "x".

Comment: Yes! Thanks for making that clear.